# Can't load images into PhotoView without losing quality or causing memory exception

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide

I was using Glide to load images into PhotoView to create a visualization with zoom and multiple pages, however even setting the format to DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888 the image quality is bad when zooming.

Then I went to Picasso, however it is causing Out of Memory exception for images with 1028 x 1580 pixels. How can I display this images in a better quality, allowing zooming and switching pages (if I display them on a WebBrowser, the quality is better even when zooming)?

Here is the code of the PagerAdapter:

```
static class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private final List<Uri> pageList;

        public SamplePagerAdapter(List<Uri> pageList) {
            this.pageList = pageList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return pageList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            PhotoView photoView = new PhotoView(container.getContext());
            /*Glide.with(container.getContext())
                    .load(pageList.get(position))
                    .asBitmap()
                    .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
                    .into(photoView);*/

            Picasso.with(container.getContext()).load(pageList.get(position)).into(photoView);

            // Now just add PhotoView to ViewPager and return it
            container.addView(photoView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

            return photoView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == object;
        }

    }
```

Comment: use uri instead of bitmap

Comment: With Glide I need to use asBitmap() to be able to set the format to ARGB_8888, though the images are all loaded using Uri even with Picasso

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this? I'm in the same situation, being forced to choose between poor image quality and OOMs.